# delete element in array with vue not working

Tags: vuejs2, splice

I have components parent and child when i apply splice to delete element in the data the count is correct but in the view (html) is not reactive

Helpme
This is my parent component

```
data(){
    return {
      unit: this.unit_prop,
      weeks: this.unit_prop.weeks,
      error_in_form:false
      }
  },
  methods:{
    addWeek(){
      const unique_key=  new GenerateKey(this.weeks.length).unique_key;
      const number_week = this.weeks.length+1;
      this.weeks.push( new WeekDTO(unique_key, number_week) );
    },
    removeWeek(index){
      this.weeks.splice(index,1);
      const elob = this.weeks[index];
      console.log(elob);
      elob.number_week=44;
      console.log(elob.number_week);
      //this.$emit('watch','WeekSilabus');
      this.$set(this.weeks[index],'number_week', 40);

    }
  },
  watch:{
    weeks: (arr_weeks)=>{
      arr_weeks.forEach((element,index) => {
        //element.number_week = index+1;

      });

    }
  } 
}
```

and when i remove a week this change apply in the data but not refresh to the component view

Comment: are you sure this is correct ? this.$set(this.weeks[index],'number_week', 40); shouldn't it be this.$set(this.weeks, index, 40) ? did you read the documentation on the vue site about this ? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats

Comment: Of course with this code i edit the value but is not reactive for my view

Comment: How do you pass the data to the child component?